# Автообновление через AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Здравствуйте! Уменя такой вопрос. Есть форум. Там стоит система голосования через `AJAX`. Но при нажатии на `"+"` или `"-"` оценка не меняется сразу, только через `f5`. Можно ли сделать это без перезагрузки страницы? Вот код:

```
$('button[id=up]').live.click(function(){
id=$(this).parent().attr('id');
pm=1; //означает, что надо будет прибавить 1
// p=$(this).parent().parent().$('p').text();
// alert(p);
    $.ajax({
        url:"add.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: {id:id, pm:pm},
        //beforesend: alert("1"),
        success: function(d){alert(d)}
    }); 
});
```

А вот и `index.php`:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        //row[0] eto id
        $t.="<span>$row[1] (id #<span id=$row[0]>$row[0]</span>)<div><form id=$row[0]><button id='up'>+</button><button id='down'>-</button></form><p>$r</p></div><br>$row[3]<hr /></span>";
        $w++;
    }
echo $t;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Можно](http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-ajax/)

Не вижу проблем, отсылай запрос на сервер, там его обрабатывай, ну и возвращай на страничку ответ, допустим

Отослал ты параметр $_POST['good']=*ID_вопроса или ответа*, в ответ должен получить что-то типа *OK_ID_вопроса или ответа*, и если получил, то поменяй на страничке элемент HTML, в котором указана старое значение.

Все просто.

```
$('button[id=up]').live.click(function(){
id=$(this).parent().attr('id');
pm=1; //означает, что надо будет прибавить 1
// p=$(this).parent().parent().$('p').text();
// alert(p);
    $.ajax({
        url:"add.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: {id:id, pm:pm},
        //beforesend: alert("1"),
        success: function(d){
     if d=тому на что проверяешь{
             // получаешь значение
             var num = parseInt($("# ID элемента для обновления").text());
             // потом тебе нужно новое записать туда
              num=num+1; // ну или -1 смотря плюсуешь или минусуешь
             $("# ID элемента для обновления").text(num);
             }
        }
    }); 
});

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        //row[0] eto id
        $t.="<span>$row[1] (id #<span id=$row[0]>$row[0]</span>)<div><form id=$row[0]><button id='up'>+</button><button id='down'>-</button></form><p>$r</p></div><br>$row[3]<hr /></span>";
        $w++;
    }
echo $t;
```

Брррр....

> span id=$row[0]>$row[0] // что за бяка?
>
> <p>$r</p> // а это что такое?
>
> Я просто не понимаю какие данные ты вытаскиваешь из Таблицы.
> **(id #<span id=$row[0]>$row[0]</span>)** вот тут ты типа делаешь вывод оценки?

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: @Shrek, я обновил вопрос. Вы можете сделать выборку этого элемента для обновления? У меня пока не получается это сделать.

Comment: @Shrek, в `$row[0]` у меня хранится `id` сообщения. `<p>$r</p>` - а эта "бяка" как раз и показывает рейтинг сообщения. Ее нужно изменить.(Сделать выборку).

*Забыл!*

`$r=row[4]` - это рейтинг в БД.

Comment: Вот! это уже правильнее.
Как у тебя на странице этот рейтинг выводится, он единственный элемент на странице или их много?

Comment: В том и дело что их много. Различаю я их по id сообщения. А как дальше выбрать - не знаю. :-\

Comment: Так ты хочешь чтобы сообщения учавствовали в рейтинге а не вопросы?

тогда так

<p id="mes_123">100</p>

<p id="mes_1123">0</p>

<p id="mes_12311">1</p>

ну а выбирать их

             var num = parseInt($("#mes_12311").text());
             // потом тебе нужно новое записать туда
              num=num+1; // ну или -1 смотря плюсуешь или минусуешь
             $("#mes_12311").text(num);

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Надо только заставить обработчик голоса при ajax-запросе выдавать текущую оценку.